# Browser Not Responding to DOM Class Changes with Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom

his is a rather strange one, I fear there may not be a solution.

I have a linux box running arch-linux, matchbox in kiosk mode, using midori and /or luakit webkit browsers.

Pages are served from node.js & express, there is client javascript running node and pure javascript on the client browser DOM.

What appears to be happening, is that randomly, the browser stops responding to DOM changes, for example, changing div classes to hide/show different divs on keypress (touchscreen) events.

I have added a debug div, that fires at the end of the class change, and gets and displays the div data, and the data displayed confirms that the javascript has fully executed, and the div's classes have been correctly changed.

I have tested this using midori and luakit and both show exactly the same problem, this NEVER happens when using any browser on a PC.

Not sure what additional info I can provide, any suggestions on how I can debug what is / what is not happening, as other than showing the results of the js function, I'm at a loos as to what else to do ?!

## EDIT

There are no errors reported, works flawlessly on the PC, Here's an example of the kind of thing I am doing:

```
//css
.panel { display: none;}
.show { display: inline-block;}

//js
function showPanel(g_focold,g_focnow){
    g_focold.className="panel"; 
    g_focnow.className="panel show";
}

//html
<div class="panel" id="div1">Panel 1</div>
<div class="panel" id="div2">Panel 2</div>
```

Comment: None of the question tags refer to a programming language :-?

Comment: Thanks, I have added text saying that i am using node.js to serve and pure javascript to control the bowser client-side dom.

Comment: I've added the tags myself. Please note that potential answerers don't normally find questions via search box.

Comment: Without code it is hard to make sense of what you actually mean...

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors?